# Regex for currency formatting - java

Tags: java, regex, currency-formatting

I want to add the filter to my `EditText` with accepts different currency values like,

US currency format: **123,456.00**

Spanish currency format: **123.456,00**

**Also, I want to keep maximum 10 digits before the decimal point and max 2 digits after the decimal.**

My regex for filtering EditText value is `(([0-9|(,.)]{0,13})?)?((,.)[0-9]{0,2})?`

But this regex accepts values like `,,,,,,,` or `.......`

How to change this regex which strictly accepts both currency format with the same pattern?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern could match repeating dots or repeating comma's only because all the parts are optional due to the question mark. It could also match an empty string.

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with a repeating group that starts with a dot or comma followed by 3 or 2 digits to prevent consecutive dots and commas:

**Explanation**

```
^(?:(?![,0-9]{14})\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?|(?![.0-9]{14})\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d{1,2})?)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?![,0-9]{14})` Negative lookahead, assert not repeating 14 times a comma or digit
  - `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match 1-3 digits, repeat 0+ times matching a comma followed by 3 digits, optionally match a dot and 1-2 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?![.0-9]{14})` Negative lookahead, assert not repeating 12 times a dot or digit
  - `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:\,\d{1,2})?` Match 1-3 digits, repeat 0+ times matching a dot followed by 3 digit, optionally match a comma and 1-2 digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUfSdH/1)

Comment: Thank you, One more thing, I want to keep maximum 10 digits before the decimal point and max 2 digits after the decimal. How to add that?

Comment: @The fourth bird, thanks but how will this regex match for *1,234,567,890.89*? As I want max 10 digits before decimal?

Comment: @Kavita_p honestly regex may not be a good choice here.  Though it is achievable, it is hardly maintainable.

Comment: The negative lookahead seems strange: `1,234,567,890` is valid and it has 13 repetitions, which your pattern will exclude

Comment: @AdrianShum I have updated the lookahead and made the decimal parts optional.

Answer (score 1):

[NumberFormat's getCurrencyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance-java.util.Locale-) method has a Locale parameter. This is the standard way to handle your problem of formatting currencies.

Comment: Thank you, But here I want to add a filter for my edit text field. I don't want to allow users to add any value in the edit text field

Comment: I'm confused -- not the first time, and you're not the first person who has mind you -- so join me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/192295/hd1?tab=general) and help to enlighten me, please?